# How can i read string from local file?

Tags: javascript, html, file, input, local

How can i read files by specifying "file path" by using javascript?

i am lazy to manually click input button and select them every times.

i also tried to cheat it by use JQUERY to do but it seems like jquery can not modified input value.

Any other suggestion to dealing with local file is welcome. Thank you

Comment: JavaScript won't read local files, except cookies.

Comment: No you can't. It's for security reasons.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor And except for HTML5 Local Storage. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons javascript is running in a sandbox environment inside the browser and you cannot access the file system on the client computer.

If that was possible by only navigating to a website, the author of this website could access any file on the client computer. That's not something that people browsing the internet usually want.

---

UPDATE:

Using the [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) you have the possibility to access the contents on the client of files that were explicitly loaded by the user in an `<input type="file">` fields or were for example drag and dropped from the desktop. But the user must explicitly perform this action. You cannot access arbitrary files.

Comment: The File API doesn't allow you to read arbitrary files from the file system. It allows you to read files that were for example drag and dropped into the webpage or loaded in an `<input type="file">` field. This should be done with the explicit intent of the user.

Comment: It doesn't, but it does let you access the file system under controlled conditions.

Comment: Yes, but the `<input type="file">` also allows you to access the file system on the server. It's true that with HTML5 you could read the contents of this file on the client. Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer to include your remark.

Answer (score 2):

> How can i read files by specifying "file path" by using javascript?

You can't.

> i am lazy to manually click input button and select them every times.

You have to. That is how the user gives the web application permission to access the files.